# Increasing iteration speed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration

Good afternoon,

I'm iterating through a huge Dataframe (104062 x 20) with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df_tot = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\XXXXXXX\\LOGS\\DF_TOT.txt", header=None)

df_tot = df_tot.replace("\[", "", regex=True)
df_tot = df_tot.replace("\]", "", regex=True)
df_tot = df_tot.replace("\'", "", regex=True)

i = 0

while i < len(df_tot):
    to_compare = df_tot.iloc[i].tolist()

    for j in range(len(df_tot)):
        if to_compare == df_tot.iloc[j].tolist():

            if i == j:
                print('Matched itself.')
            else:
                print('MATCH FOUND - row: {} --- match row: {}'.format(i,j))

    i += 1
```

I am looking to **optimize time spent** for each iteration as much as possible, since this code iterates 104062(^2) times. (More or less ten billions iterations).

With my computing power, time spent comparing `to_compare` in the whole DF is around 26 seconds.

I want to clarify that  in case it would be needed, the whole code could be changed with faster constructs.

As usual, **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: in general,  you **don't** iterate. And also remember to include a sample data and expected output from the data.

Comment: It's not that clear to me, I would really appreciate if you could explain to me how could I pursue my goal elseway.

Comment: What's `soggetto` ?

Comment: It was the previous name of ```to_compare``` and i just forgot to swap it, edited anyway, thanks for making me aware of the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i understand, You just want to find duplicated rows.

Sample data(2 last rows are duplicated):

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8], [1,2], [5,6]], columns=['a', 'b'])
        df
Out[1]: 
            a   b
        0   1   2
        1   3   4
        2   5   6
        3   7   8
        4   1   2
        5   5   6
```

This will return all duplicated rows:

```
In [2]: df[df.duplicated(keep=False)]
Out[2]: 
            a   b
       0    1   2
       2    5   6
       4    1   2
       5    5   6
```

And indexes, grouped by duplicated row:

```
In [3]: df[df.duplicated(keep=False)].reset_index().groupby(list(df.columns), as_index=False)['index'].apply(list)
Out[3]: a  b
        1  2    [0, 4]
        5  6    [2, 5]
```

You can also just remove duplicates from dataframe:

```
In [4]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[4]:     
            a   b
        0   1   2
        1   3   4
        2   5   6
        3   7   8
```

Comment: That is exactly what i was looking for. The only question I have is:
```(...).groupby(['a', 'b']```
Inside Squared parenthesis do i have to specify all columns of my dataframe case I would match em all?

Comment: @Gianmarco Marandola shortly - yes, but i changed `(...).groupby(['a', 'b']` to `(...).groupby(list(df.columns)` to specify all columns

Comment: Awesome, @Dmitriy K. so I suppose that if I don't get results after launching this script line ther shouldn't be any duplicate, right?